# Run a JGNAT program?

Tags: java, jvm, ada

I just installed JGNAT on Windows (**gnat-gpl-2010-jvm-bin.exe**)

This is a sample code **hello.adb** from the included manual:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
 procedure Hello is
 begin
    Put_Line ("Hello GNAT for the JVM.");
 end Hello;
```

First, compile it: *jvm-gnatmake hello.adb*

```
jvm-gnatcompile -c hello.adb
jvm-gnatbind -x hello.ali
jvm-gnatlink hello.ali
```

Looks fine. So let's run it: *java hello*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jgnat/adalib/GNAT_libc
    at hello.main(hello.adb)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jgnat.adalib.GNAT_libc
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Is the GNAT_libc class file at the indicated location? Is the CLASSPATH set? Is an install guide or release notes included in the distribution, and if so is there any mention of post-installation activities that need to be done?

Comment: It looks like it could be a problem related to native code bridge.

Comment: @trashgod - That would be much better advice were someone to have seen fit to actually provide him with an answer.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Good point, but I see 19 questions with 25 answers, zero accepted, zero votes and no response to @Marc C's helpful comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the fix.  You must set the classpath to the jar file containing GNAT_libc.class.

```
java -cp C:\GNATPRO\2010\lib\jgnat.jar;. hello
```